# Zend framwork which db function do connection to the database

Tags: php, zend-framework

Which zend db function connect to the database ?

```
$select = new Zend_Db_Select(Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter());
$select->from(array("t" => "table1"), "*")
    ->from(array("t2" => "table2"), null)
    ->where("t.id>0")
    ->order("id");
$query = $select->query();
$lines = $query->fetchAll(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
```

**query();**

or

**fetchAll();**

Answer (score 1):

Connection is made in adapters method `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract:_connect`. `Zend_Db_Select` buids sql and its `query` method calls adapters method `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::query`.
So connection is made in `query`